# Greasemonkey automatically load forum redirects

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I have very little knowledge in javascript and greasemonkey, so I hope someone here would be kind to answer this easy (I think) question!

Several forums have a redirect page when you click a link that links outside the forum, and you have to click "Continue" to load the page.

The URL of the redirect page can for example be constructed like this:

https://www.forumurl.com/out/?http://outsideurl.com

How should this Greasemonkey script to automatically load http://outsideurl.com when I visit the above forum url look like?

Answer (score 0):

**We could to plug ajax and write this code**

$("buttonID").click(function(){$("body"/* or your favorite content*/).load( "your url")});